# in my case, i need to convert entire json object into encryption format. How can i convert?

Tags: java, spring-boot

JSONObject inputParams = new JSONObject();
JSONObject encryptDatas = new JSONObject();

```
        inputParams.put("referenceid", referenceid);
        inputParams.put("sourcetype",sourcetype );
        inputParams.put("source", source);
        
        byte[] encryptedJson=PasswordUtils.encryptJson(inputParams);
        String encryptedInput=new String(encryptedJson);


public static byte[] encryptJson(JSONObject inputParams) throws Exception {
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectStream= new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
    objectStream.writeObject(inputParams);
    byte[] serializedObject=byteStream.toByteArray();
    String key="qPNNbUwcSOhXgWGwdBOXopjgSNPynDkC";
    byte[] keyByte=key.getBytes();
    byte[] hashedKey=generateHash(keyByte);
    
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec=new SecretKeySpec(hashedKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    byte[] encryptedObject=cipher.doFinal(serializedObject);
    return encryptedObject;
    
}
```

i'm trying to convert entire json object into encypted data then i should given the input for the converted json data, here error throughing encryption method .Here i should follow the AES ECB PCKS5Padding algorithm.

Comment: And what happens when you run this?  Does it work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this??

```
        JSONObject inputParams = new JSONObject();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byteStream.writeBytes(inputParams.toString().getBytes());
        String key = "AKeyForYourValue?";
        MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashedKey = sha256.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(hashedKey, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedObject = cipher.doFinal(byteStream.toByteArray());

        System.out.println(new String(encryptedObject));
```

not sure i understand your question correctly or not